# Why my @Async Future<T> blocks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have 2 Synchronous methods, the following one does not block.

```
@RequestMapping("/send1")
    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> sendMail() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("sending mail 1..-"
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 16);
        System.out.println("sending mail 1 completed");
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);
    }
```

But the following one blocks.

```
@RequestMapping("/send3")
    public void callAsyn3() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
Future<Boolean> go = sendMail3("test");
}

@Async
public Future<Boolean> sendMail3(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean acceptedYet = false;
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 12);
        if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            acceptedYet = true;
        }
        return new AsyncResult<>(acceptedYet);
    }
```

They are in the same controller class, Why such different behavior?

Comment: In the second case you call internally method. so the `@Async` is ignored (not proxyed method called).

Comment: How would I invoke it manually?

Comment: if you want to do what you are doing you need to switch to cglib proxy instead of jdk proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case you call internally method. so the @Async is ignored (not proxyed method called).

There are two ways to fix

The first one is to ntroduce a separate bean (e.g. MyService) and move the annotated with `@Async` method there.

The second way is Autowire the controller to itself

@Controller
public class MyController {

```
@Autowired
private MyController myController;

@RequestMapping("/send3")
public void callAsyn3() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
     Future<Boolean> go = myController.sendMail3("test");
}

@Async
public Future<Boolean> sendMail3(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean acceptedYet = false;
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 12);
    if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        acceptedYet = true;
    }
    return new AsyncResult<>(acceptedYet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling method in the same class do not pass through the proxy. So you can not use a method with `@Async` in the same class and make calls asynchronous.

We can create another service and write the `@Async` method there. Something like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> sendMail3(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean acceptedYet = false;
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 12);
        if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            acceptedYet = true;
        }
        return new AsyncResult<>(acceptedYet);
    }
}
```

This will run asynchronously ( non-blocking ).

If you want to do this in the same controller, you can submit it manually to some thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

you have self-invocation , call method sendMail3 from method callAsyn3 directly. it doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.
simple fix - you should get contoller from context and call callAsyn3 from this instance.
normal fix - create new service - asyncSendMailComponent/Service, move sendMail3 into asyncSendMailComponent , inject asyncSendMailComponent into you controller and call sendMail3

in controller :

```
@Autowired
private AsyncSendMailComponent asyncSendMailComponent;
@RequestMapping("/send3")
    public void callAsyn3() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
Future<Boolean> go = asyncSendMailComponent.sendMail3(msg)
}
```

Async service

```
 @Service
    pubclic class AsyncSendMailComponent {
    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> sendMail3(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
            boolean acceptedYet = false;
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 12);
            if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                acceptedYet = true;
            }
            return new AsyncResult<>(acceptedYet);
        }
    }
```